# How to create a long positive integer

Tags: python, string, integer, numbers, zero

I am sorry if this question may sound a bit trivial for those who are more expert than me. If I have to create a long positive integer as well as find the number of zeros (with the following instruction as a hint: change the number to a string), do you know what I am supposed to do? Actually, these are some of the notions and examples that I'm focusing on to solve this problem.

[image]

I do not know whether the blue highlighted lines may be suitable for the assignment. There is no specified other info (if you are wondering, I have downloaded python 3.10, although typing the command python onto the panel of commands prompt, it pops up that the python's version in use is 3.6.6).

I am very sorry for this kind of question but I have just started moving my first step towards Python.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is considered *long*? Three digits, thousand digits, a billion digits?

Comment: Actually I think that hundred digits should be ok

Comment: What are the boundaries for your "long positive integer"? How long? Should it be a random number or will you apply some other algorithm to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert an `int` to a `str` using `str()` and then count the number of zeros,
this can be done using the `findall()` function from `re`

```
import re 
len(re.findall('0', str(number)))
```

`findall()` returns a list of all the occurrences that match the regex in the first argument, here '0' will only match a zero, the second argument is the string to check, here we pass the number cast as a string using `str()`. as `findall()` returns a list of occurrences we can pass the function as an argument to `len()` to get the number of occurrences

you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: You don't need *re* for this. *str(number).count('0')* is all that's required

Comment: @ArthurKing: Please make that an answer, it's a better one.

Answer (score 3):

To find the number of zeroes in an integer without the aid of additional modules:

```
n = 1001001 # for example

print(str(n).count('0'))
```

**Output:**

```
4
```